# PostgreSQL v9.5+ UPSERT

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert, postgresql-9.5

It looks like PostgreSQL v9.5 got support for INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING/UPDATE http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=168d5805e4c08bed7b95d351bf097cff7c07dd65

I want to do something like this

```
UPSERT INTO "myScheme"."myTable" (id, a, b, c) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $5) WHERE id = $4'
```

How to achive this result taking into considiration that I am using PostgreSQL v9.5+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be like this:

```
INSERT INTO myScheme.myTable(id, a, b, c) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
ON CONFLICT (id) DO
UPDATE SET a=$2, b=$3, c=$4;
```

If there is no record with `id=$1` then it will do insert. Otherwise it will update existing record.